# Selecting some elements based on conditions

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, slice

I have `RA` and `DEC` and `z` of few elements. They sort of denote the x,y,z positions of the elements.

They are values stored in arrays.

The **`max(z) = 3.0`**, it is third dimension I have not shown here.

What I would like to do is to, remove those elements inside the box in the picture below according to certain conditions and give me those elements outside the box (with also **`z<1.0`**)

[image]

So from the example in the picture, ***I need all those elements outside the black box*** along with a **third condition** ***`z<1.0`***

What I have tried and is **not working is the following**:

```
data_z = contains all the z values
data_RA = contains all the RA values
data_DEC = contains all the DEC values

ra_lim = np.array([[40.0,43.0],[43.0,46.0],[46.0,50.0]])
dec_lim = np.array([[4.0,8.0],[0.0,4.0],[-2.0,0.0]])

new_z = data_z[(data_z<1.0) * ~(data_ra>ra_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_ra<ra_lim[0][1])
                     * ~(data_dec>dec_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_dec<dec_lim[0][1])]

new_RA = data_RA[(data_z<1.0) * ~(data_ra>ra_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_ra<ra_lim[0][1])
                         * ~(data_dec>dec_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_dec<dec_lim[0][1])]

new_DEC = data_DEC[(data_z<1.0) * ~(data_ra>ra_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_ra<ra_lim[0][1])
                         * ~(data_dec>dec_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_dec<dec_lim[0][1])]
```

So basically the

```
~(data_ra>ra_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_ra<ra_lim[0][1])
                         * ~(data_dec>dec_lim[0][0]) * ~(data_dec<dec_lim[0][1])]
```

**should denote the box** and the **`~`** sign should give me the **inverse condition**. i.e. exclude the values within this box and give me back the remaining values.

But this doesn't seem to work. **How do I go about getting the values outside the box also with the third condition `z<1.0`**???

Comment: what is the shape of RA, DEC and z?

Comment: @JulienSpronck They are all 1 dimensional with equal `len(RA)==len(DEC)==len(z) = 35000`

Comment: Why do you select with an inverse operator, and don't you inverse the comparison operator? So instead of `~(data_ra<ra_lim[0][1])`, use `(data_ra>=ra_lim[0][1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example that works:

```
x = np.array([1,5,7,9,4,5,6,8,9,0,3])
y = np.array([2,4,5,7,3,2,6,2,7,8,3])
```

Let's say you want to get all elements outside the box defined by (x < 6, y < 5). The box is represented by (x < 6) * (y < 5). If you want the outside of the box, you take the inverse of that: `~((x < 6) * (y < 5))`. This is equal to `~(x < 6) + ~(y < 5)` instead of `~(x < 6) * ~(y < 5)` (as written in your code).

```
mask = ~(x < 6) + ~(y < 5)
print x[mask]
print y[mask]
## [7 9 6 8 9 0]
## [5 7 6 2 7 8]
```

In your case, the mask should be

```
mask = (data_z<1.0) * ~((data_ra>ra_lim[0][0]) * (data_ra<ra_lim[0][1])
                     * (data_dec>dec_lim[0][0]) * (data_dec<dec_lim[0][1]))
```

Comment: Sometimes just a small mistake will lead us to problems!! That was the case. I had everything right except the repeating `~` ! !